# Storing CHUNK X and Y positions to a scoreboard in Minecraft Java 1.19.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So when you forceload a chunk, it says something like this:
Chunk [62,-2] added to forceload
That's basically it
I want to store the first number in that list, as "chunkx", and the second number stored as "chunkz". I would like to get the chunk x z that the player is in, and I would like to store each x z into the two scoreboard dummies. Someone please help me! I have tried many things, and I am not that good with NBT's

Answer (score 1):

I stored my x position and my z position as a scoreboard "x", and "z", then I duplicated that scoreboard by setting it to "storeX" and "storeZ", so I can still use "x" and "z" scoreboards, without changing their values in an operation.
I created the scoreboard objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add z dummy
/scoreboard objectives add x dummy
/scoreboard objectives add storeZ dummy
/scoreboard objectives add storeX dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Positions dummy
/scoreboard objectives add ChunkZ dummy
/scoreboard objectives add ChunkX dummy
/scoreboard objectives add 16 dummy
/scoreboard players set @a 16 16
```

Then I ran the commands in a datapack (If somebody wanted to do this without a datapack, just make the scoreboards with the lines above, and put each of these lines below into separate repeating command blocks (except for #comments)):

```
execute store result score @a z run data get entity @a[limit=1] Pos[2]
execute store result score @a x run data get entity @a[limit=1] Pos[0]
scoreboard players operation @a storeZ = @a z
scoreboard players operation @a storeX = @a x

execute store result score @a ChunkX run scoreboard players operation @a storeX /= @a 16
execute store result score @a ChunkZ run scoreboard players operation @a storeZ /= @a 16



#STORE POSITIONS ON SIDEBAR: OPTIONAL
scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Positions

scoreboard players operation X Positions = JKWarrior15 x
scoreboard players operation Z Positions = JKWarrior15 z
scoreboard players operation ChunkX Positions = JKWarrior15 ChunkX
scoreboard players operation ChunkZ Positions = JKWarrior15 ChunkZ
#--------------------------------------------
```

I don't usually work with datapacks, but I became so impatient that I just grinded for like 2 hours straight problem solving...